# Command not found after installing @vue/cli

Tags: vue.js, vue-cli

I npm installed [@vue/cli](https://cli.vuejs.org/) with `npm install -g @vue/cli`.  but when I try the vue command I get `-bash: vue: command not found`.   I added `export PATH="/usr/local/Cellar/node/11.2.0/lib/node_modules/@vue/cli/bin:$PATH"` to my bash profile and when I echo path in terminal I get

```
/usr/local/opt/openssl/bin:/usr/local/Cellar/node/11.2.0/lib/node_modules/@vue/cli/bin:/Users/jimmymona/.node/bin:/Applications/Postgres.app/Contents/Versions/latest/bin:/usr/local:/usr/local/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/bin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/Applications/Postgres.app/Contents/Versions/latest/bin:/Applications/Postgres.app/Contents/Versions/latest/bin:/usr/local:/usr/local/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/bin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin
```

Which does have the path to the vue cli in it: `/usr/local/Cellar/node/11.2.0/lib/node_modules/@vue/cli/bin`

I also tried sudo installing it but that didn't work either
Anyone know what the issue is?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The path is wrong. The binary resides in `/usr/local/Cellar/node/11.2.0/bin` rather than `.../lib/...`.

As you'll notice, the file in the latter directory is named as `vue.js`, not `vue`.
NPM creates a symlink without the `.js` extension to it in the `bin` directory, and that's the actual binary we typically refer to.

Typically we don't use the full path in `.bashrc` directly (in case the npm global path changes).
Rather, it's recommended to calculate it by combining the result of `npm config get prefix` and `/bin`, i.e.

```sh
export PATH="$PATH:$(npm config get prefix)/bin"
```